# how to import three in react ,i want to add 3dmodal in web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

i want to use three.js in react

```
import THREE from 'three';
```

i use npm add three.js ,but got :THREE is undefined;

so, how import, what's wrong

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, threejs could not be installed through NPM. You should install it manually by appending it as `script` tag in your html. An example with React.

```
import React from 'react'   
import scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader'

@scriptLoader(['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.js'])
export default class ThreeReact extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props )       
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps ({ isScriptLoaded, isScriptLoadSucceed }) {
    if (isScriptLoaded && !this.props.isScriptLoaded) { // load finished
      if (isScriptLoadSucceed) {
        console.log(THREE)
      }
      else this.props.onError()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>          
         Threejs loaded with React.
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: you probably should clarify that `@scriptLoader` is a es7 language feature